# Show Toast when recording time exceeds two mins in media recorder

Tags: android, time, limit, android-mediarecorder

I implemented Media Recorder to record the voice in android.I tried to limit the recording time to two mins by

```
     mRecorder.setMaxDuration(120000);
```

It works fine.But I want to show the alert if recording time exceeds 2 mins.I did not find any code or related tutorial regarding this.Can anyone help me?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for the `setMaxDuration(...)` method (see the bold text)...

> Sets the maximum duration (in ms) of the recording session. Call this after setOutFormat() but before prepare(). **After recording reaches the specified duration, a notification will be sent to the MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener with a "what" code of MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED** and recording will be stopped. Stopping happens asynchronously, there is no guarantee that the recorder will have stopped by the time the listener is notified.

So basically all you need to do is implement an `OnInfoListener` and send your alert / notification from there.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Show alert" in your question title. Do you want a `Toast`, a popup `Dialog`, a `Notification` in the status bar? There are different ways of doing all of these and plenty of sample code out there.

Comment: The guide for creating toasts...  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

Comment: I know to create toast.I didn't aware of MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED and MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener

Comment: Well just create the `OnInfoListener` the same way you'd create an `OnClickListener` for a `Button` etc.

Comment: @micky : OK, glad to help. Sorry I couldn't give specific code as you hadn't really provided much of your own code. All I'd say is whenever dealing with "media" classes check the Android docs for the various "listener" interfaces. As I said, you can normally just use them the same way as 'click' or 'touch' listeners. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

:)

```
mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```